# Python SQL-native alternatives to ORM

Tags: python, sql, orm

I feel like ORM is an overkill, with its overall complexity of inner structure and very specific syntax. It does provide a comfortable abstraction over the SQL record data types, yet it doesn't seem natural nor does it seem needed in most cases.

I couldn't find any alternatives, though. What I mean is basically this kind of code:

```
select_user_by_id = from_sql('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %s')
...
# later usage:
admin = select_user_by_id(1)
# any function returns a named-tuple, so dot notation is available
if admin.is_online:
    pass  # and so on
```

SQL is a statically typed language, and python is a dynamically typed one, so it doesn't matter what type is returned from the query, a programmer wouldn't need to worry about that. AND a programmer wouldn't need to worry about the actual columns the query returns, because the return type is a named tuple.

So, there is a ton of value: **you can write native SQL code inside your python code and "compile" it to a python function, which ALWAYS returns just what you need, even if the underlying query is rewritten**.

For those, who know SQL, it seems like a blessing: **no need to learn complex ORM APIs and everything is still a python object out of the box**. But I haven't seen this kind of module. Maybe it's just unpopular?

*I've started a github repo for this kind of functionality, but it lacks SQL syntax analysis, so you have to manually tell the function, what it should return for each query (a row, a scalar or rows).* [Github link](https://github.com/make-itrain/nativegres/blob/main/nativegres.py).

Question is: **is there a ready solution for this kind of functionality? If not, maybe there is a python-based SQL analyzer, so that I could get rid of manually writing the return type of the query? What can one do to fully automatize the** `sql_code -> python function` **process?** The code is going to be in the repo, so just in case everyone can use it and commit.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @KlausD. is there such package already is my question.

Comment: Requests for software libraries are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not the greatest trick! Of cause you want more than a yes or no, you want the library to be named! :-\

Comment: @KlausD. but I've provided a codebase too, which I'm currently using in a project. It's not a concrete question, a rather vague one (provided, there isn't a solution yet), but again as for me I'm really shocked there is no alternative to an ORM, which seems stupid. I don't know how to phrase the question 
any other way.

Comment: @KlausD. ok, lemme try one thing.

Comment: @KlausD. now that's more like it.